# CC command not found on openresty installation

Tags: nginx, cc, openresty

I am not very familiar with Linux and I have just started learning about nginx and nodejs. Since I work with Windows I tried to install openresty through MinGW by running:

```
tar xvf ngx_openresty-1.9.7.1.tar.gz
cd ngx_openresty-1.9.7.1/
./configure
```

but I get the following error:

```
platform: msys (msys)
cp -rp bundle/ build
cd build
cd LuaJIT-2.1-20151219
Can't exec "cc": No such file or directory at ./configure line 588.
make TARGET_STRIP=@: CCDEBUG=-g CC=cc PREFIX=/usr/local/openresty/luajit
==== Building LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta1 ====
make -C src
make[1]: cc: Command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/ngx_openresty-1.9.7.1/build/LuaJIT-2.1-20151219/src'
make[1]: cc: Command not found
make[1]: cc: Command not found
make[1]: cc: Command not found
make[1]: cc: Command not found
make[1]: cc: Command not found
Makefile:262: *** Unsupported target architecture.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/ngx_openresty-1.9.7.1/build/LuaJIT-2.1-20151219/src'
make: *** [default] Error 2
ERROR: failed to run command: make TARGET_STRIP=@: CCDEBUG=-g CC=cc PREFIX=/usr/local/openresty/luajit
```

Is there something additional that I need to install? 
GCC exists and its version is 3.4.4 (msys special)

Answer (score 1):

make sure  that you have install `c`  & `c++`  in your linux

you can try

```
yum install gcc
```

to install the compiler .
GNU Compiler Collection   including C、C++、Objective-C、Fortran、Java、Ada&Go